# I want to display related product based on subcategory using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show related products based on a subcategory. in this menu when I click the parent category it shows products but on the click of subcategory product is not showing, I want to show product when I click subcategory.

Does anybody have any idea?

thanks in advance for your help :)

category table

[image]]
product table

```
product has  id product_name ,product_image,price,cate_id
```

**video**

please watch video for better understanding thanks
https://www.loom.com/share/5b91deedac154c98bc275c9edcd3b773

**Category Model**

```
public function category()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\category','p_id');
 }
```

**controller**

```
public function procateg(Request $request){
 $cate_name=$request->cate_name;       
 $product=DB::table('category')
 ->leftjoin('products','category.id','=','products.cate_id')  
 ->where('category.cate_name','=',$cate_name)->paginate('8');    
  return view('front_end/products',compact('product'));   
 }
```

**HTML view**

```
<div class="nav-panel__nav-links nav-links">
    <ul class="nav-links__list">
        @foreach(App\category::with('category')->where('p_id',0)->get() as $firstmenu)
            <li class="nav-links__item  nav-links__item--has-submenu ">
                <a id="cate" class="nav-links__item-link" href="{{url('/product/'.$firstmenu- 
        >cate_name)}}">
                    <div class="nav-links__item-body">
                        {{$firstmenu->cate_name}}
                        <svg class="nav-links__item-arrow" width="9px" height="6px">
                            <use xlink:href="{{url('public/assets/images/sprite.svg#arrow-rounded-down-9x6')}}">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="nav-links__submenu nav-links__submenu--type--megamenu nav-links__submenu-- 
         size--nl">
                    <!-- .megamenu -->
                    <div class="megamenu ">
                        <div class="megamenu__body">
                            <div class="row">
                                @foreach($firstmenu->category as $secondmenu)
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <ul class="megamenu__links megamenu__links--level--0">
                                            <li class="megamenu__item  megamenu__item--with-submenu ">
                                                <a href="{{url('product'.'/'.$firstmenu->cate_name.'/'.$secondmenu->cate_name)}}">
                                                    {{$secondmenu->cate_name}}</a>
                                                <ul class="megamenu__links megamenu__links--level--1">
                                                    @foreach($secondmenu->category as $thirdmenu)
                                                        <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="{{url('product'.'/'.$firstmenu- 
          >cate_name.'/'.$secondmenu->cate_name.'/'.$thirdmenu->cate_name)}}">
                                                                {{$thirdmenu->cate_name}}</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .megamenu / end -->
                </div>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Route**

```
 Route::get('product','FrontController@product');
 Route::get('product/{cate_name}','FrontController@procateg');
```

Comment: why you create a question then delete it then create again with the same question?

Comment: It seems you want to display products, but retrieving from categories table, based on your relationship, there should be relation between product and category too and using that relationship, you should be able to retrieve products.

Comment: Add to your query: 

->select('product.*','category.*')

Comment: i have used this query but same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Category Model**

```
public function category()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\category','p_id','id');
}
```

**controller**

```
public function procateg(Request $request){
   $cate_name=$request->cate_name;       
   $product  = DB::table('category')
             ->Join('products','category.id','=','products.cate_id')  
             ->where('category.cate_name','=',$cate_name)->get();    
   return view('front_end/products',compact('product'));   
 }
```

Comment: after applying your code when  i click subcategory it seems 404
Not Found not working

Comment: Happy coding :)